# Get AWS IoT MQTT data on my EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt

I have been trying to figure out AWS IoT for weeks, and I keep running into the problem of not being able to forward my mqtt data anywhere. I have an EC2 server running nodejs, and a raspberrpi running nodejs & python.

The Pi CAN successfully publish topics and info (can be read on the mqtt test panel), but I'm not really sure where to go from here as to directing the traffic. The device is a properly registered 'thing'.

Long story short, I've figured out how to send and receive AWS IoT MQTT messages, but I don't know how to have my ec2 el server interact with them.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much there. I think you're just misunderstanding how AWS IoT works.

It handles all the routing for you with a [pub/sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern. Basically all you need to do on your server or any other device is "subscribe" to a topic in order to receive the messages. When something publishes a message to a topic in AWS IoT, it will automatically send it to all open "subscribers."

Messages are not persistent on the platform, meaning that messages are essentially lost unless there are subscribers listening for them. So don't expect a subscriber to receive the messages sent before it came online.

You can use any of their SDKs (i.e. their [python sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python)) to both publish and subscribe to topics.

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for. I already use python to handle most of my sending, what would be the best way to subscribe and print information in a js/php (I can do either) format? And how would I go about validating and subscribing to a specific topic from awsiot? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Check the samples in the repositories. The data format for messages is effectively JSON, so python can easily parse it (as I'm sure the JS sdk's can) and you could dump the data to JSON as well. Not sure what you mean by validating.

Comment: I could've used more precise language, found a simple guide that goes over how to validate my request (through certs and whatnot). What I'm really trying to ask is how to subscribe and print these messages on a webpage, and publish messages to the sender effectivly. I found some good tuts on pushing mqtt data to dynamodb but I'm wondering if there is a more straightforward subscribe function I could use in js/php. Is this article (http websockets) a good place to start? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html

Comment: I believe so, I personally haven't tried doing this with websockets, but I'm sure it's not too bad. The thing to note is that you need an IAM credential to use websockets I believe, as opposed to the identity files for a "thing" in IoT (at least that's the case with the python sdk).

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to manage incoming messages for later use.  For an AWS IoT data flow you normally would always want to use DynamoDB and S3 as they are extremely cheap to usually free.  You can create an action in AWS IoT to directly place data objects into a Dynamo Table from AWS IoT or dump them into a Bucket with either Kinesis firehose or a Lambda function.  Don't try to use the direct to s3 premade function on AWS IoT core because it wont concatenate incoming objects into the same folder.

Now once you have your DB and poor mans data lake in S3 you can easily ingest the data from an EC2 instance by simply requesting the S3 URL or bringing in the Dynamo Data table.  Also I wouldn't recommend managing your own Node.js backend.  Just use Dynamo, its cheaper and easier to start.